# Javascript debugger asking to open another instance of visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

I am working on many projects with VS 2015.  On one of them, after the (document).ready I put debugger; which usually opens the current instance of VS to follow the JS, but this one does not - it asks to open a new instance of VS.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Here's pic of what I am seeing:
[image]

Comment: Hi, it might be related to upgrading a project to a new version, please try to delete the .csproj files and the .sln file for the project, rebuild and debug it again, then it could be opened in the same current instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you show a screen shot about this issue? Whether it met the crashed issue which called the JIT debugger tool?

Comment: @Dean.DePue, You could disable the JIT debugging under TOOLS->Options->Just-In-Time: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, if it was not related to the JIT, would you please share us the main code? So we could repro it in my side.